How to do X25519 ECDH with a round of HSalsa20 to produce the shared secret key specified by NaCl and libsodium using BouncyCastle?
While trying to implement the "Authenticated encryption" scheme of libsodium using BouncyCastle I naively performed simple X25519 key agreement to obtain a javax.crypto.SecretKey object.
I.e.:
public SecretKey generateSecretKey(PrivateKey privateKey, PublicKey publicKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("X25519", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    keyAgreement.init(privateKey);
    keyAgreement.doPhase(publicKey, true);
    return keyAgreement.generateSecret("X25519");
}

I used this secretKey as an input to the org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.XSalsa20Engine:
XSalsa20Engine xSalsa20Engine = new XSalsa20Engine();
xSalsa20Engine.init(true, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(secretKey), nonce));

However, reading the Cryptography in NaCl paper, and subsequent testing, I found that this is wrong.
Quote:

In the next step, described in Section 7, Alice will convert this 32-byte shared
secret k into a 32-byte string HSalsa20(k, 0), which is then used to encrypt and
authenticate packets. Bob similarly uses HSalsa20(k, 0) to verify and decrypt
the packets. No other use is made of k. One can thus view HSalsa20(k, 0) as the
shared secret rather than k.

The secret key produced by the KeyAgreement needs to be first run through a round of HSalsa20(k, 0). to produce the final key, called a "shared secret key" in the original paper by Bernstein, that is then used for encryption.
TLDR
How can I perform a round of HSalsa20 on the initial SecretKey object I got from X25519 exchange using BouncyCastle? There is no standalone HSalsa20 function implementation in Bouncycastle library. It seems to be implemented somehow implicitly as a part of the (X)Salsa20Engine class, and I'm not able to invoke it out of the message encryption context.

I'm not familiar with the library but, presumably, that's all done internally in the XSalsa20Engine class. Since you supply the key and the nonce to the class in its init method it has all the information it needs to compute HSalsa20(key, 0) and the other values.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Unfortunately, no. I verified this by debugging the libsodium library. The secretKey value I got is different, and matches the one from libsodium only after a round of HSalsa20. When I tried to do the encryption using the secret key I got from BC KeyExchange I got a completely different ciphertext. When I injected my secretKey bytes into libsodium, I got the same ciphertext output as with BouncyCastle, so clearly my secretKey value is wrong.

So you're not using a libsodium Java library, you're using Bouncycastle to try to replicate the output from libsodium?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Exactly.

The comments in the source code for Xsalsa20Engine().init suggest that it is following the steps in that paper. I don't know what's going wrong.

You can use BouncyCastle for an implementation of HSalsa20 based on an answer to one of your last questions:

BouncyCastle implements XSalsa20Engine as derivation of Salsa20Engine.
XSalsa20Engine overwrites setKey(), which implements HSalsa20 and
internally determines subkey and subnonce. When the XSalsa20Engine
instance is initialized, Salsa20Engine#init() is executed and thus
setKey().

This offers the following path for an implementation of HSalsa20: Implement a class HSalsa20 that derives from Salsa20Engine and take the logic from XSalsa20Engine#setKey():
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.Salsa20Engine;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Pack;

class HSalsa20 extends Salsa20Engine
{
    public byte[] getData(byte[] keyBytes, byte[] ivBytes) 
    {
        super.setKey(keyBytes, ivBytes);
        
        Pack.littleEndianToInt(ivBytes, 8, engineState, 8, 2);

        int[] hsalsa20Out = new int[engineState.length];
        salsaCore(20, engineState, hsalsa20Out);

        engineState[1] = hsalsa20Out[0] - engineState[0];
        engineState[2] = hsalsa20Out[5] - engineState[5];
        engineState[3] = hsalsa20Out[10] - engineState[10];
        engineState[4] = hsalsa20Out[15] - engineState[15];

        engineState[11] = hsalsa20Out[6] - engineState[6];
        engineState[12] = hsalsa20Out[7] - engineState[7];
        engineState[13] = hsalsa20Out[8] - engineState[8];
        engineState[14] = hsalsa20Out[9] - engineState[9];

        byte[] result = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
            outputStream.write( Pack.intToLittleEndian(engineState[1] ));
            outputStream.write( Pack.intToLittleEndian(engineState[2] ));
            outputStream.write( Pack.intToLittleEndian(engineState[3] ));
            outputStream.write( Pack.intToLittleEndian(engineState[4] ));
            outputStream.write( Pack.intToLittleEndian(engineState[11] ));
            outputStream.write( Pack.intToLittleEndian(engineState[12] ));
            outputStream.write( Pack.intToLittleEndian(engineState[13] ));
            outputStream.write( Pack.intToLittleEndian(engineState[14] ));
            result = outputStream.toByteArray();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); // your exception handling
        }
        
        return result;
   }
}


Test: The document you linked has test vectors for HSalsa20 in chapter 8:
import java.util.HexFormat;
...
// test vector 1
HSalsa20 hSalsa20 = new HSalsa20();
byte[] test1 = hSalsa20.getData(
        new byte[] {0x4a,0x5d,(byte)0x9d,0x5b,(byte)0xa4,(byte)0xce,0x2d,(byte)0xe1,0x72,(byte)0x8e,0x3b,(byte)0xf4,(byte)0x80,0x35,0x0f,0x25,(byte)0xe0,0x7e,0x21,(byte)0xc9,0x47,(byte)0xd1,(byte)0x9e,0x33,0x76,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x9b,0x3c,0x1e,0x16,0x17,0x42}, 
        new byte[16]);
System.out.println(HexFormat.of().formatHex(test1)); // 0x1b27556473e985d462cd51197a9a46c76009549eac6474f206c4ee0844f68389

// test vector 2
hSalsa20 = new HSalsa20();
byte[] test2 = hSalsa20.getData(
        new byte[] {0x1b,0x27,0x55,0x64,0x73,(byte)0xe9,(byte)0x85,(byte)0xd4,0x62,(byte)0xcd,0x51,0x19,0x7a,(byte)0x9a,0x46,(byte)0xc7,0x60,0x09,0x54,(byte)0x9e,(byte)0xac,0x64,0x74,(byte)0xf2,0x06,(byte)0xc4,(byte)0xee,0x08,0x44,(byte)0xf6,(byte)0x83,(byte)0x89}, 
        new byte[] {0x69,0x69,0x6e,(byte)0xe9,0x55,(byte)0xb6,0x2b,0x73,(byte)0xcd,0x62,(byte)0xbd,(byte)0xa8,0x75,(byte)0xfc,0x73,(byte)0xd6});
System.out.println(HexFormat.of().formatHex(test2)); // 0xdc908dda0b9344a953629b733820778880f3ceb421bb61b91cbd4c3e66256ce4

The outputs generated correspond to those of the test vectors.

This allows Libsodium's crypto_box (public key cryptography) to be implemented with BouncyCastle as follows:

Create a (32 bytes) shared secret k1 with X25519 (as described in the question)
Create a (32 bytes) key k2 with HSalsa20(k1, 0) (as described above, s. test vector 1)
Perform XSalsa20-Poly1305 with k2 (as described in this answer)

